# Auto submit form on page load

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm having a bit of trouble with my current issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a step in a 'signup process' which I don't need anymore, but I don't have time to reconfigure the entire process so I'm trying to auto submit the form on page load so it will basically skip over this step. Any thoughts?

EDIT: Sorry, I should mention, originally there were two submit options, I got rid of one, now I just want to submit the 'mem_type' option on page load. not sure if that makes much of a difference.

```
<form method=post action="<?=$base_href.url("signup")?>" name="member_signup">
<input type=hidden name="process" value="facility_info">
<input type=hidden name="create_order" value="true">

<?php
    foreach ($_POST as $k=>$d) {
        if ($k === 'textarea') continue;
        echo "<input type=hidden name=\"".strip_tags($k)."\" value=\"".strip_tags($d)."\">";
    }
?>

<input type="submit" value="submit" name="mem_type" border="0">
</form>
```

Comment: Give the `form` an `id` attribute, then run this **after** your form: `document.getElementById("form_id").submit();`

Comment: @Ian Your comment should be an answer.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Try this
On window load submit your form.

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.forms['member_signup'].submit();
}
```

Comment: thsi worsk perfect but somehow it tries to open the form on a popup so I gets blocked by browser, any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: @Spring In situations like this, make sure you don't have a "target" on your form that points away from the page. (eg. `target="_blank"`)

Answer (score 25):

You can submit any form automatically on page load simply by adding a snippet of javascript code to your body tag referencing the form name like this....

```
<body onload="document.form1.submit()">
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: However, with IE11, I'm loosing my URL parameters when performing so.

Comment: I was stuck for a few hours today, unable to get this to work, even though I have implemented something like this many times.  The problem turned out to be my form contained a input with type="submit" name="Submit" id="submit".  Removing the id attribute fixed it, I don't understand exactly why this is, especially with the cross up of id and name and but I am posting it here in case someone is having a problem submitting a form this way.  I'd say watch out for names in the DOM colliding with the name of the function you need to run.

Answer (score 11):

Add the following to `Body` tag,

```
<body onload="document.forms['member_signup'].submit()">
```

and give `name` attribute to your `Form`.

```
<form method="POST" action="" name="member_signup">
```

Answer (score 3):

If your `form` doesn't have an `id` you can use,

```
<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
```

This will submit the first form found on the page.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way it worked for me, because with other methods the form was sent empty:

```
<form name="yourform" id="yourform" method="POST" action="yourpage.html">
    <input type=hidden name="data" value="yourdata">
    <input type="submit" id="send" name="send" value="Send">
</form>
<script>            
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            document.createElement('form').submit.call(document.getElementById('yourform'));
            });         
</script>
```